# Boolean operator confusion in a function

Tags: javascript, boolean

I wrote a function to find the missing letter in the passed letter range and return it. If all letters are present in the range, it should return undefined.

Here is my code:

```
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length;i++ ) {
    if(str.charCodeAt(i+1) - str.charCodeAt(i)>1) {
     return String.fromCharCode(str.charCodeAt(i)+1);
    }
  }
 return undefined;
} 
fearNotLetter("bcd");
```

Now this code right here works, but previously, in the **if statement**, instead of **>**, I used **!==** and the function didin't work for the cases, where I should be getting `undefined`. Instead of it, I got a letter or some symbol.

Why did that happen, and why the code above works properly ?

Comment: !== should be != I'm pretty sure in javascript !== isn't an operator? i may be wrong however

Comment: This code is invalid.  `str.charCodeAt(i+1)` will try to read past the end of `str`

Comment: @ChrisHutchison: `!==` is an operator in JavaScript.

Comment: good to know, thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting, though, that both with `< str.length` and `!== str.length`, that `str.charCodeAt(i+1)` is going to give you `NaN` on the last loop iteration.

Comment: Post the code with the problem, not the code that works. And show the sample input you supplied, along with the unexpected result that you got.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's probably the issue. Those two operators will give opposite results every time when given `NaN` as an operand.

Comment: @squint: I wasn't reading carefully enough and thought they were using it in the loop condition. Indeed, that probably is the crux of the matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the last iteration of your loop, this line:

```
if(str.charCodeAt(i+1) - str.charCodeAt(i)>1) {
```

...compares `NaN` with the last character in the string, because `str.charCodeAt(i+1)` is trying to get the code *beyond* the last character.

`NaN > anyNumber` is always `false`, but `NaN !== anyNumber` is always `true`.

You probably want to stop your loop at `< str.length - 1`.